# Is there a difference between "Path planning" and "Pathfinding"?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, path-finding

Doing some reseach about ("pathfinding"|"path planning") I've found many algorithm all basicly doing the same thing (finding a way from point A to point B with more or less constraints), and I couln't found any difference between pathfinding and path planning algorithms.

Is there a real difference between those two type of algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real difference. Perhaps some researchers use the terms with different meanings in mind, but to most people I think they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

There are graph traversal algorithm to find a water, phone or sewer grids. This is different from finding a shortest path from a to b but this algorithm can be tweaked to find the grid. A simple example is a minimal spanning tree.

Answer (score 0):

Pathfinding is finding the shortest path, path planning is mapping out the possible paths.
you need the letter to do the former